# create service using searchd command of Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

```
    I make index on one Sphinx compatible xml document.It runs success fully.
Then i make service using searchd command.Following is command to make service
```

searchd --install --config "path for config file" --servicename "servicename" --port "portnumber".

```
If Sphinx config file is put inside Sphinx directory then service create and start successfully.

But if config file is not inside Sphinx directory then service created successfully but it can not start successfully.

Should i change something inside searchd block in config file?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the the documentation (http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#ref-searchd) all parameters specified when creating the service is called when starting the service.

--install installs searchd as a service into the Microsoft Management Console (Control Panel / Administrative Tools / Services). Any other parameters specified on the command line, where --install is specified will also become part of the command line on future starts of the service. For example, as part of calling searchd, you will likely also need to specify the configuration file with --config, and you would do that as well as specifying --install. Once called, the usual start/stop facilities will become available via the management console, so any methods you could use for starting, stopping and restarting services would also apply to searchd. Example:

C:\WINDOWS\system32> C:\Sphinx\bin\searchd.exe --install --config C:\Sphinx\sphinx.conf

The above command means that the config file must always exist at C:\Sphinx\sphinx.conf.

If your "path for config file" exists and the service still does not start, then I would suggest creating a bug at http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/main_page.php so it cab be resolved.

In the meantime, put the config file in the Sphinx directory where it works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a log folder in the sphinx folder. If you check the searchd section of the config file, it will have an option for where the log files and pid are to be placed. If the directory does not exist, then the service will not start.

Comment: Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)